# How to read data from Google Sheets into PHP

Tags: php, excel, csv, curl, spreadsheet

Okay, so I've been stumped on this for a few days, unable to find anything that conclusive.

I have a spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zeH_eiptclgeBIOFavppagsVNYj35wQRcRMO2KJwLg0/edit#gid=1856558677

There are headers going across in row 1 and down in column A. It works as a type of grid so you can determine a certain score, for example Aatrox X Ahri is 100, which is in C2.

I understand that I'd most likely have to pull the CSV and work with that in PHP, but I'm really not sure about how.

I have no idea how to go about accessing this spreadsheet cleanly without tons of overhead and messy code, nor do I know how I would really get the specific scores for the columns.

If I'm not being clear, please let me know and I'll try to clarify. I'm really at a standstill until I figure out how to handle this.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? You already "found" the magic words (php,csv,excel) try google and you'll find plenty of examples. Try them out and if you cannot get it to work show us your tried implementation and maybe we could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to google into Google API. The specific API you need is this one: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

To be able to use it, you need to have authorized access to it: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests

Google API take some time to learn, so sit down, clear your head and take the time to read the documentation.

Also, for PHP, you may want to have a look to this library:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Look at this example on how they use the Drive service of the API to upload a file
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/fileupload.php

The Drive service also have a method to download a file.

Comment: May I also suggest using Google Fusion instead of Google spreadsheet. Google Fusion is really designed to handle SQL queries, which is not the case for Spreadsheet.

Comment: GOogle Fusion is experimental app still.